# Would language restrictions for fastest-code problems be ok?

Tags: discussion

In my last meta post, I asked about [why we need objective winning criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria).  Martin made a really good point that we need objective scoring to motivate users to improve their code.

That said, the argument is a bit weak when it comes to [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenges.  Because [answers have to be run on a single machine](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code), times that users post are mere estimations.

To counteract this, **would it be a good idea to require all answers to be in Javascript, and have a stack snippet that runs all of the answers on a page?**  Users would be able to compare their answers to the current submissions, and would be motivated to improve their code further.

(Note: I'm not saying that the OP doesn't need to run the submissions themselves for the final scores)

Comment: I'm pretty sure yes. I've seen [tag:fastest-code] challenges which do that

Comment: @Doᴡɴɢᴏᴀᴛ while I haven't looked through all of them, the only example I can think of is Golf CPU, which is a different scoring mechanism IMO.

Comment: I think this isn't actually such a bad idea (we've done the same for KotHs) but the main problem is that the relative performance of different solutions can vastly depend on the browser being used.

Comment: Usually yes for language on other platform ^_^

Answer (score 0):

### Generally speaking, no.

For [fastest-code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fastest-code) challenges, the OPs typically restrict the allowable language to the set of those freely available for their operating systems. Anything further than that would be disallowing a more or less arbitrary set of languages, which is very sternly frowned upon here. So while you *can* post a language-specific fastest code challenge, it will not likely be well received.