# Fix the sandbox link in our info box

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, hyperlinks

Due to changes in sorting the sandbox link in our info box no longer works as intended.  It should sort by active, but it doesn't.

The existing link is:

```
https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=active
```

The fixed link should be:

```
https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc
```

The new text we would like is:

> [Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange!](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange) This is a site for recreational programming competitions, not general programming questions. Challenges must have [an objective scoring criterion](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria), and it is highly recommended to first post proposed challenges in the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc).

```
<a href="https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20861/welcome-to-code-golf-and-coding-challenges-stack-exchange">Welcome to Code Golf and Coding Challenges Stack Exchange!</a> This is a site for recreational programming competitions, not general programming questions. Challenges must have <a href="https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8130/why-do-we-have-objective-winning-criteria">an objective scoring criterion</a>, and it is highly recommended to first post proposed challenges in the <a href="https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges?answertab=modifieddesc">Sandbox</a>.
```

This is not pressing but we would like if this could be fixed by the SO devs by replacing the existing content with the updated content.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377910) (on the main Meta Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We've updated the link with your recommendation.

Thanks for reporting and providing the HTML ready to go! You rock.